# Does Kratos' total level matter?

Tags: god-of-war-2018

Above the list of attributes is a number that I understand to be Kratos' level. This seems to be based on the level of the various pieces of equipment, as far as I could tell so far.

Enemies also have a level displayed, and enemy health bars get a different color depending on how difficult they are, which I assume is based on this level.

My question now is whether this number in itself changes anything? Do I get stronger if I increase my level ignoring the stat changes the higher level gear provides? Or is there something like bonuses and penalties when fighting enemies at higher levels than yourself?

The main reason I suspect that it might matter is that the stat differences in gear seem mostly inconsequential. I'm only level 2 right now, but now I'm running into several level 5-6 enemies in side quests, and I often don't fare well against those enemies. So I need better gear, but I'd like to know if focusing on the gear level or specific stats matters.

Answer (score 8):

**Are enemy health bars and levels based on your own?**
No they are not. Enemies have a set level, regardless of the difficulty. Between Balanced and Give me a story at least. The colour of their health bar represents the difference in level between your gear level and theirs. Purple being the hardest, through orange and yellow to green which is the easiest. If you were gear level 4 a level 7 enemy would have a purple health bar.

**Does gear level mean anything?**
Yes it does. This represents the strength of Kratos. Higher level gear will provide larger stat bonuses and thus make your character stronger. This is how you progress your characters strength in the game.

**Bonuses or penalties for distant level enemies**
Needless to say, lower level enemies are easier and higher are much harder. It's not uncommon to run into a purple bar enemy a few levels higher than you in a side quest who will kill you with one hit. I am unsure of the impact on earned experience with killing enemies higher or lower level than you.

**Gear stats**
The stats on gear will get better with higher level and higher rarity gear. Green is common, Blue is Rare, Purple is Legendary and Gold is Epic. Generally I've found that higher rarity gear drops with a better base level and with much higher stats. This allows you to upgrade it much further.

**Focus on stats or gear?**
Focus on gear. This is the primary driver for progressing the strength of Kratos. Different gear sets focus on different stat combinations. So the style of gear you pick will depend on your playstyle.

**How do I get more gear recipes?**
The items to craft are unlocked when you first encounter an ingredient required to make an item. As you play and explore, ingredients will become available and shops will offer new items, even if you don't have all the ingredients required to craft the item.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, that is "does Kratos overall level have any impact?". I.e. is there a benefit in using some worse (stats-wise) gear to push Kratos 1 level up instead of using superior but lower-level gear.

Comment: Worse stat gear will not raise your level, that isn't how the gearing system works.

Comment: from my experience it IS how works. At least it looked like it did so. The overall level only took the gear level into account. So, for example, if I had level 6 gear with some stat equal to 8 and level 7 gear with the same stat less or equal to 7 (all other stats the same cons specials), the latter gear would still increase overall level.

Comment: @DanM. You should post your findings as an answer for other users to read :)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm two enchantments i have both have Luck+4 and no perk, yet are level 2 and 4. Also i have lots of enchantments with far superior stats to higher level items. Therefore higher gear level certainly does not guarantee higher stats. So the issue of "Stats vs Char Lv" exists. Finally my testing with Valkyries confirms Char Lv does impact damage and defence at least. I'd guess a % modifier is applied when you are of a different level. Overall (within reason) Char Lv i find is more important on testing than stats alone (ignoring perks).